# Edit: Switch cell position in List but also in data array when mixing UIKit and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have List with an array of TextFields

```
struct MyView: View {
@State var options: [DatePollOption] = [DatePollOption(date: ""),DatePollOption(date: "")]
var body: some View{
    List{
        Section{
            ForEach($options) { $option in
                HStack{
                    PickerTextField(
                        placeholder: "GG", date: $option.date)
                    
                }
            }
            .onMove(perform: move)
        }
    }
}
    
func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    options.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    
}
}
        struct DatePollOption : Identifiable {
            var id: String = UUID().uuidString
            var date : String?
        }
```

I can move cells around but order in `options` data array always stays the same. How to switch index positions of elements in arrays to always match order in list?

Edit: Im really sorry for wanting help and not providing enough informations...

```
        class Helper{
            public var dateChanged : (()-> Void)?
            public var doneButtonTapped: (()-> Void)?
            
            @objc func dateValueChanged(){
                self.dateChanged?()
            }
            
        }
        struct PickerTextField : UIViewRepresentable{
            var textField = UITextField()
            @State var datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
            let toolbar = UIToolbar()
            let helper = Helper()
            
            public var placeholder: String
            @Binding public var date: String?
            
            
            @Binding var dates : [DatePollOption]
            var dateFormatterDate : DateFormatter = {
                let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyy"
                return dateFormatter
            }()
            
            
            
            
            func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
                self.datePickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
                self.datePickerView.addTarget(self.helper, action: #selector(self.helper.dateValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
                
                self.textField.placeholder = self.placeholder
                self.textField.inputView = self.datePickerView
                textField.delegate = context.coordinator
                
                self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
                
                self.helper.dateChanged = {
                    
                    date = dateFormatterDate.string(from: self.datePickerView.date)
                    
                }
                
                return self.textField
            }
            func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
                return Coordinator(datePicker: $datePickerView, date: $date, textField: textField, toolBar: toolbar)
            }
            
            func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
                if let selectedDate = self.date {
                    uiView.text = selectedDate
                }
                
                
            }
            
            
            class Coordinator: NSObject,UITextFieldDelegate,UIToolbarDelegate{
                
                
                
                @Binding var datePicker : UIDatePicker
                var textField : UITextField
                @Binding public var date: String?
                let toolBar : UIToolbar
                var dateFormatter : DateFormatter = {
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                    return dateFormatter
                }()
                let helper = Helper()
                
                
                init(datePicker: Binding<UIDatePicker>,date: Binding<String?>,textField: UITextField,toolBar: UIToolbar) {
                    
                    self._datePicker = datePicker
                    self._date = date
                    self.textField = textField
                    self.toolBar = toolBar
                    super.init()
                    
                    
                    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonaction))
                    
                    
                    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)
                    
                }
                
                @objc func doneButtonaction(){
                    if self.date == nil {
                        self.date = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datePicker.date)
                        self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
                        //print(dates.count)
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
```

The problem is when I change the order of cells inside List and try to edit date it is changing date to different cells to one that was there before change.
I guess I dont communicate well between SwiftUI and UIKit

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? You’re missing some important code here (like where `dates` is declared, among other things)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jnpdx Fell very dumb for wanting help without providing enough info.. I hope you can help me now

Comment: At first glance it looks like your DatePickerView shouldn’t be `@State`. Haven’t had time to test, though.

Comment: I am changing its mode from date to time and vice versa inside coordinator so I think I needed it to be state @jnpdx